# ASP.NET. Redirecting older browsers. 

Tags: asp.net

I'm building a web app that uses a lot of CSS3 and session storage. My goal is to deny users of older browsers by redirecting them to a "we don't support your browser" page. I'm thinking of using an http module that looks at the incoming request. In the client page I would encode a hidden field that contains the user agent version.

I want this to work for both regular aspx requests and ajax requests to asmx files. What would a good method to do this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [HttpRequest.Browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.browser.aspx) property to detects browser type in [ASP.NE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yekbd5b.aspx)T and have a look at article by Scott Mitchell - [Performing Browser Detection Using ASP.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150659/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120402-1.aspx).

Comment: ah coool, I didn't know you could also do this on the server. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you would need to encode anything onto the page.  Create a module that detects the browser, or the version of javascript the browser supports (for example), using the [Http.Browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3k2ssx2.aspx) capabilities.

Comment: try out this, it will get you the data you need about your browser

         System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities browser = Request.Browser;